# Tag Synonyms: [email-to-case] and [email2case]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we create a synonym link between [email-to-case] (125 questions) and [email2case] (303 questions)? I lack the 5 answer points in either tag to use the official suggestion mechanism, but it seems clear that these tags mean the same thing.  I'll leave it to those with the points to decide which is the tag and which the synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a synonym and merged `[email-to-case]` into `[email2case]`, as the latter had significantly more traffic.